# How can I begin to track down this Wi-Fi problem?

Tags: 14.04, boot, wireless, drivers, grub2

This is not your run-of-the-mill "what's wrong with my Wi-Fi" question, I'll guarantee you that...

I inherited a [Lenovo Ideacentre Stick 300](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/ideacentre/stick-300/) and have been trying to get Windows 10 off of it and Ubuntu onto it. The hardware seems to be the same as the much more popular [Intel Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html), so I've been starting with walkthroughs like [these](http://liliputing.com/2015/07/install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-the-2gb-intel-compute-stick.html) to get up and running. Ubuntu 14.04 actually installs, boots, and runs a full GUI with working Wi-Fi and sound. But I discovered a bizarre problem that I'm not sure how to even begin tracking down:

My use case for this machine calls for it to run headless, and as such I figured it would be a waste to always start the full GUI. So I went into `/etc/default/grub` and changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

and then I ran `sudo update-grub2`. After rebooting, my Wi-Fi performance was *terrible*. Dropped packets, ping times in the 700ms range, and so much lag that SSH was practically unusable. I set the cmdline back to `"quiet splash"`, rebooted, and it went back to normal.

As a second test, I booted back into `"text"` and, as expected, saw horrible performance. I ran `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start` over an SSH connection and almost immediately the Wi-Fi performance became acceptable. Once lightdm started, killing it had no effect on the performance.

How on earth can I start tracking down the correlation between Wi-Fi performance and whether or not the GUI has been started? The driver is the Realtek rtl8723bs, which seems to have a track record of being not-very-good.

Comment: That's pretty strange. What version of Linux are you using (uname -rv)?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste `3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 23:20:00 UTC 2015`

Comment: What Ubuntu version did the installation media have? If it was 14.04.3, it should have installed a kernel newer than 3.16. The first thing to try is installing a new kernel. For future reference, please use up-to-date installation media. Run 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily', reboot, and see if that helps any.